# How to load a content to modal with ajax while using Spring MVC frame work

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, spring, bootstrap-modal

New to ajax and bootstrap modal, I am trying to implement an edit functionality with bootstrap modal. I need the content in DB to be loaded to the modal when user click edit link.I am doing this with ajax and below is how i implemented it however, i am getting the following error on browser:

> -script.js:62 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'on' of undefined
>       at script.js:62 (anonymous) @ script.js:62 (line where my ajax function starts)

Could someone please help. Thanks.

code Snippet:

my JSP: (the edit link to load the modal)

```
    <c:forEach var="customer" items="${customers}" varStatus="status">
                                        <tr>
                                            <td><c:out value="${status.count}" /></td>
                                            <td><a title="Go to the Company Certificate Detail">${customer.customerName}</a></td>
                                            <td>${customer.contactName}</td>

                                            <td>${customer.street}</td>
                                            <td>${customer.state}</td>
                                            <td>${customer.zipCode}</td>
                                            <td>${customer.country}</td>
                                            <td>${customer.email}</td>



                                            <td>
                                                <div class="btn-group">
                                                    <button type="button"
                                                        class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle"
                                                        data-toggle="dropdown">
                                                        Actions <span class="caret"></span>
                                                    </button>
                                                    <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
                                                        <li><a data-toggle="modal" data-target="#editCustomerModal" data-customer-id="${customer.id}">Edit Customer Detail</a></li>

                                                        <li><a data-toggle="modal" data-target="#deleteCustomerModal_${customer.id}" >Delete Customer</a></li>
                                                    </ul>
                                                </div>
                                            </td>

                                        </tr>

                                        <!--Delete Customer Modal  -->




</c:forEach>
```

My Edit Modal:(outside the forEach tag)

```
<!--Edit Customer Modal  --> 

<div id="createCustomerModal" class="modal fade" role="dialog">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                Edit Customer
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">



                <table class="form-table">
                    <tbody>
                    <tr>
                    <td><input type="hidden" id="customerId" path="#" class="form-control" /></td></tr>
                        <tr valign="top">
                            <td style="width: 25% !important;"><label
                                class="not-required" for="pool-name">Customer Name:</label></td>
                            <td><input type="text" id="customerName" title="Company Name" path="#"
                                class="form-control" /></td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr valign="top">
                            <td style="width: 25% !important;"><label
                                class="not-required" for="expire-after">Contact Name:</label></td>
                            <td><input type="text" id="contactName" path="#"
                                class="form-control" /></td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr valign="top">
                            <td style="width: 25% !important;"><label
                                class="not-required" for="description">Street:</label></td>
                            <td><input type="text" id="street" path="#"
                                class="form-control" /></td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr valign="top">
                            <td style="width: 25% !important;"><label
                                class="not-required" for="description">State:</label></td>
                            <td><input type="text" id="state" path="#"
                                class="form-control" /></td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr valign="top">
                            <td style="width: 25% !important;"><label
                                class="not-required" for="expire-after">Zip-Code:</label></td>
                            <td><input type="text" id="zipCode" path="#"
                                class="form-control" /></td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr valign="top">
                            <td style="width: 25% !important;"><label
                                class="not-required" for="expire-after">Country:</label></td>
                            <td><input type="text" id="country" path="#"
                                class="form-control" /></td>
                        </tr>

                        <tr valign="top">
                            <td style="width: 25% !important;"><label
                                class="not-required" for="expire-after">Email:</label></td>
                            <td><input type="text" id="email" path="#"
                                class="form-control" /></td>
                        </tr>

                    </tbody>
                </table>


            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <div>
                    <input type="submit" id="createNewCustomer" value="Save"
                        class="btn btn-default" onClick="alert('To be Implemented');" />
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                </div>

            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

My script.js:

```
$(document).on('shown.bs.modal','#editCustomerModal', function () {

    var customerId = this.dataset.customerId;
    var id = $('#customerId').val(customerId);
    //var customerId= $('#customerId').val();
    var customerName= $('#customerName').val();
    var contactName= $('#contactName').val();
    var email= $('#email').val();
    var street= $('#street').val();
    var zipCode= $('#zipCode').val();
    var state= $('#state').val();
    var country= $('#country').val();

    $.ajax({
        type: "post",
        url: "/UtilityCertificateWebApplication/edit?id=" + customerId,
        cache: false, 
        contentType:'application/json',
        dataType: 'json',
        data:"customerName="+ customerName + "&contactName=" + contactName +  "&street=" + street +
          "&state=" + state + "&zipCode=" + zipCode + "&country=" + country +"&email=" + email ,
        success: function(response){
            alert("inside edit modal");
            var obj = JSON.parse(response);
            $('#customerName').val(obj.userName);
            $('#contactName').val(obj.userName);
            $('#email').val(obj.userName);
            $('#street').val(obj.userName);
            $('#zipCode').val(obj.userName);
            $('#state').val(obj.userName);
            $('#country').val(obj.userName);
        },
        error: function(){                      
            alert('Error while edit request..');
        }
    }); 


});
```

Answer (score 1):

Your issue is in this line:

```
$("#editCustomerModal_")+$('#customerId').val().on("show.bs.modal", function() {
```

Change that line to:

```
$("[id^=editCustomerModal_").on("show.bs.modal", function() {
```

Now, your issue is getting the source customerid? For this you can write  inside your modal show event:

```
var customerId = this.id.replace('editCustomerModal_', '');
```

In any case, I'd suggest to use only one modal. This means you need to change this line:

```
<li><a data-toggle="modal" data-target="#editCustomerModal_${customer.id}">Edit Customer Detail</a></li>
```

to:

```
<li><a data-toggle="modal" data-target="#editCustomerModal" data-customer-id="${customer.id}">Edit Customer Detail</a></li>
```

Now, your issue is: how to get the customer id when the modal shows:

- add a listener on anchor click
- get the customer id as: this.dataset.customerId

```js
$('[data-target="#editCustomerModal"]').on('click', function(e) {
    var customerId = this.dataset.customerId;
    $('#customerId').val(customerId);
})
$("#editCustomerModal").on("show.bs.modal", function (e) {
    var customerId = $('#customerId').val();
    console.log(customerId);
});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>


<!-- Button trigger modal -->
<ul>
    <li><a data-toggle="modal" data-customer-id="222" data-target="#editCustomerModal">Edit Customer Detail: 222</a></li>
    <li><a data-toggle="modal" data-customer-id="333" data-target="#editCustomerModal">Edit Customer Detail: 333</a></li>
</ul>
<!-- Modal -->
<div id="editCustomerModal" class="modal fade" type="hidden">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                Edit Customer
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                <table class="form-table">
                    <tbody>
                    <tr>
                        <td><input type="hidden" id="customerId" path="#" class="form-control" /></td></tr>
                    <tr valign="top">
                        <td style="width: 25% !important;"><label
                                class="not-required" for="pool-name">Customer Name:</label></td>
                        <td><input type="text" id="customerName" title="Company Name" path="#"
                                   class="form-control" /></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr valign="top">
                        <td style="width: 25% !important;"><label
                                class="not-required" for="expire-after">Contact Name:</label></td>
                        <td><input type="text" id="contactName" path="#"
                                   class="form-control" /></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr valign="top">
                        <td style="width: 25% !important;"><label
                                class="not-required" for="description">Street:</label></td>
                        <td><input type="text" id="street" path="#"
                                   class="form-control" /></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr valign="top">
                        <td style="width: 25% !important;"><label
                                class="not-required" for="description">State:</label></td>
                        <td><input type="text" id="state" path="#"
                                   class="form-control" /></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr valign="top">
                        <td style="width: 25% !important;"><label
                                class="not-required" for="expire-after">Zip-Code:</label></td>
                        <td><input type="text" id="zipCode" path="#"
                                   class="form-control" /></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr valign="top">
                        <td style="width: 25% !important;"><label
                                class="not-required" for="expire-after">Country:</label></td>
                        <td><input type="text" id="country" path="#"
                                   class="form-control" /></td>
                    </tr>

                    <tr valign="top">
                        <td style="width: 25% !important;"><label
                                class="not-required" for="expire-after">Email:</label></td>
                        <td><input type="text" id="email" path="#"
                                   class="form-control" /></td>
                    </tr>

                    </tbody>
                </table>


            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <div>
                    <input type="submit" id="createNewCustomer" value="Save"
                           class="btn btn-default" onClick="alert('To be Implemented');" />
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                </div>

            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions. As you can see in the above updated code, I have replaced all the code you suggested, I dont see any error in my browser or on server but the modal is not getting loaded with the customer data. All the text box are being loaded empty. Have i missed any from what you suggested

Comment: Take a look to my updated snippet. I proposed to change the li tags adding the data customerid.  I'll take a look tomorrow night.  I'm sorry.  Thanks

Comment: Ok, thanks for your time. I have made the changes as you suggested to the li tag as you can see above. I am not giving static value like yours though as i want the value to be dynamic,that gets fetched from DB. For every listed customer row, there is an action and it has edit option, the edit should use the customer id on that row to populate the customer values on the modal.

Comment: I have made changes to my JS file, my previous error is gone but am getting a new error  "ation/edit?id=undefined", so setting the id is not working for me. Any idea please, thanks.

Comment: this error is because **data-customer-id** is undefined on edit button inside your first modal or you don't get the value and pass it to the second modal. I assumed you have only one modal for all CRUD operations.

Comment: See the click event handler in my snippet. You need to repeat for the edit button if you open a new modal....  I hope this is enough clear. Thanks